# .htaccess 301 Path URL Restructure?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I read a lot on 301 redirects of full domains, but couldn't get how to exactly change an existing path to a new one.

Here is an example:

site.com/cars **to** site.com/motobikes

And:

site.com/cars/tires **to** sote.com/motobikes/(variable ex. Berlin, Paris)/tires

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^cars http://example.com/motorbikes [R=301,L]
```

And:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^cars/tires http://example.com/motobikes/berlin/tires [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It actually works like that. 

What I need is Berlin as a city to be a variable. should I just add (.*)$

Comment: Do you mean a querystring? Then you can just add the ?city=berlin like: http://example.com/motobikes?city=berlin

Answer (score 0):

You can make a redirect like this way in PHP

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.example.com/$var"); 
    exit();
```

Or you can use a .htaccess file `Redirect 301 /cars http://example.com/motobikes`

Comment: Good tip on using the php. Will try to implement. I need a variable after /cars/($variable).